# ReactJS not displaying backgroundImage inline CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to create a component that renders images as "tiles" or "cards" using inline CSS with ReactJS. However, I cannot figure out why the image is not displaying. I'm new to ReactJS, so this might be simply a dependency package I haven't installed - but please advise!

I bootstrapped this project from Create-React-App.

I've checked URL configuration, inline CSS syntax, and inspected the page on my local server, but I can't seem to figure out why the image won't display. I've tried to add "require" around the url, but that didn't seem to work (unless there is a specific way I need to set a url to be required?). I've also tried to use the image tag instead, having  but that displayed the tiny default image icon when the actual image fails to load.

```
import React from 'react';

function getUrl(name) {
  let string = `./images/${name}.jpg`;
  return string
}

function HorizontalTile(props) {

  let name = props.name;
  let position = props.position;
  let size = props.size;

  let url = getUrl(name);

  const divstyle = {
    height: "50vh",
    width: "100%",
    backgroundImage: `url(${url})`,
    backgroundPosition: `${position}`,
    backgroundSize: `${size}`,
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
    WebkitTransition: "all",
    msTransition: "all",
  };

  return (
    <div style={divstyle} alt={name}></div>
  )
}


export default HorizontalTile
```

I'm calling this component like this, in another JS file within the same directory:
.
.
.

```
import HorizontalTile from './HorizontalTile';
.
.
.
<HorizontalTile name="proj-hor-1" position="center" size="cover" />
.
.
.
export default Photos
```

The spacing loads fine and all the CSS elements seem to be captured, but the image doesn't appear. Any idea what I can try?

Comment: Check whether the image path is correct otherwise it looks fine to me

Comment: Did you try debugging using chrome dev tools? - I would inspect element to make sure the style is correct, then check the network tab to see if there is a 404 error on that image url.

Comment: If you are totally sure the image path exists and you are not getting a 404 on you browser console, may the background is being affected in an incorrect way by the other properties you are setting. Can you share the output if you only use the following divstyle?

`divstyle = {height: "100vh", width: "100%", backgroundImage: "url("+url+")" };`

Comment: Thanks all for the questions - @HemadriDasari image path is correct, I tested by calling the url and name of the file in the return statement, and everything checked out. I'm not getting a 404 error - in fact everything compiles great, every page loads except the image.

Comment: @JamesGarcia - I tried that the first time, same results. It compiles and everything else seems to check out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to require your images like this,

```
function getUrl(name) {
  let string = require(`./images/${name}.jpg`);
  return string
}
```

in this function, string variable is redundant. So you can return require directly.

Why the problem is resolved with require?

If we want to use without require(like in your question), we need to place our assets(images) to output directory(which is defined in your bundler(webpack) configuration). If you move your images to your output directory, your code should work.

But in the big projects, commonly we use file-loader or url-loder for our assets file. So if you use file-loader or url-loader, you should use require for importing static images.

Images(with require) are resolved like JS modules are resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your images folder? Make sure your images folder is inside the public folder and not the src folder.

```
root
├── public
│   └── images
└── src
    └── index.js
```

Comment: Hi Ronald, I tried moving to a public folder but that didn't do anything. Any other ideas on what you might try?